# Creating utf-8 database in Postgresql on Windows10

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create utf-8 database on windows 10:

```
createdb.exe -h localhost -p 53131 -U user -E UTF8 -T template0 -l en_US.utf-8 test777
```

But response is:

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_US.utf-8"
```

Any clues?

Comment: Unfortunately Postgres using the operating system support for locales so the names are different for every operating system. See e.g. here: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2011/02/27/locale-windows/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `"English_United States"` or `"en-US"`, see [the Microsoft documentation about locale names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78.aspx).

PostgreSQL allows the creation of a UTF8 database with any locale on Windows (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html)).

By the way, the `initdb` option for specifying the locale is `--locale` and not `-l`.

Comment: I was able to create a DB with "-E UTF8 --locale=american_us" but still can't force it to use utf8 collation :)

Comment: What is an UTF8 collation? Collations are for ordering strings.